# React Native - Facebook Login cannot setState

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have done a Facebook login function in my project, however i cannot `setState` when login success. I get this error `this.setState is not a function`. I tried to create a separate function call after success to `setState`, result are same, telling me my function is not a function. What should I do ?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        fblogindone:false,
     };
}


_fbAuth(){
    // Attempt a login using the Facebook login dialog asking for default permissions and email.
    LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
      function(result) {
        if (result.isCancelled) {
          alert('Login cancelled');
        } else {
          // Create response callback.
          const responseInfoCallback = function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
              console.log(error);
              alert('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
            } else {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
              this.setState({
                fblogindone:true
              });
            }
          }
          // Create a graph request asking for user email and names with a callback to handle the response.
          const infoRequest = new GraphRequest('/me',{
              parameters: {
                fields: {
                  string: 'id,name,email'
                }
              }
            },
            responseInfoCallback
          );
          // Start the graph request.
          new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()
        }
      },
      function(error) {
        alert('Login fail with error: ' + error);
      }
    );
}

render() {
  return(
      <View style={styles.topcontainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.9} onPress={()=> this._fbAuth()}>
            <FoIcon name="user-circle-o" size={33} color="#fff"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fix my own error, so I post my solution, hope can help other in future. First, I change function name to `_fbAuth = () =>{` then inside the sub function return all change to arrow function, `(result) => {` and `responseInfoCallback = (error, result) =>{` , then `this` can use inside my facebook login callback.

```
    _fbAuth = () =>{
        // Attempt a login using the Facebook login dialog asking for default permissions and email.
        LoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(['public_profile', 'email']).then(
          (result) => {
            if (result.isCancelled) {
              alert('Login cancelled');
            } else {
              // Create response callback.
              const responseInfoCallback = (error, result) =>{
                if (error) {
                  console.log(error);
                  alert('Error fetching data: ' + error.toString());
                } else {
                  this.setState({
                    fblogindone:true
                  });
                }
              }
              // Create a graph request asking for user email and names with a callback to handle the response.
              const infoRequest = new GraphRequest('/me',{
                  parameters: {
                    fields: {
                      string: 'id,name,email'
                    }
                  }
                },
                responseInfoCallback
              );
              // Start the graph request.
              new GraphRequestManager().addRequest(infoRequest).start()
            }
          },
          function(error) {
            alert('Login fail with error: ' + error);
          }
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your (this) context to the function, via arrow function or a direct bind. So you would change in the declaration of your function.

```
_fbAuth(){
```

to

```
_fbAuth = () => {
```

**OR** you'd add in your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        fblogindone:false,
     };
    this._fbAuth = this._fbAuth.bind(this)
}
```

Comment: use both `_fbAuth = () => {` and `this._fbAuth = this._fbAuth.bind(this)` also have the same result `this.setState is not a function`

Comment: I answer my own question